# Initializing a variable sized array of booleans in C

Tags: c, arrays

so I currently have a struct that looks like this:

```
typedef struct example {
    bool arr[]; //i would like this to be an array of booleans,
                //but i don't know the size right now; this is
                //probably wrong
} example_t;
```

I also have a create function that looks like this:

```
example_t *newExample(int SIZE){
    example_t *example = malloc(sizeof(example_t));
    //initialize arr to a bool array of size SIZE, ideally all false!
    example->arr = ???
    return example;
}
```

And from this, I would be able to do something like:

```
 example_t *example = newExample(MAX);
 if ( example->arr[10] )
      ....
```

Is this possible in C, to create a variable sized array of booleans?

*For Reference:* I need someway to map integers to either a `char*` or `bool`, so I can call `arr[num]` and be able to get either a string/word or a true/false value. Both ways, I'm not sure how to declare, and then initialize with a variable size. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C99 you can use [flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) where the last member can be an array without a given dimension, but there must be at least 2 members in the `struct`.

You can use a pointer (here I am using `int` instead of `bool` for brevity):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct example {
    int *arr;
} example_t;

static example_t *newExample(size_t SIZE)
{
    example_t *example = malloc(sizeof(example_t) + sizeof(int) * SIZE);

    example->arr = (int *)(example + 1);
    example->arr[5] = 5;
    return example;
}

int main(void)
{
    example_t *x = newExample(10);

    printf("%d\n", x->arr[5]);
    free(x);
    return 0;
}
```

But this doesn't make much sense, why not add a first member containing the number of elements?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct example {
    size_t size;
    int arr[];
} example_t;

static example_t *newExample(size_t SIZE)
{
    example_t *example = malloc(sizeof(example_t) + sizeof(int) * SIZE);

    example->size = SIZE;
    example->arr[5] = 5;
    return example;
}

int main(void)
{
    example_t *x = newExample(10);

    printf("%d\n", x->arr[5]);
    free(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Using this method haves an advantage: you can pass the object to any function without passing an extra parameter for the size.

Comment: I think OP asked for `bool` array initialization, not for `int` array. But the concept is same though.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by adding extra memory after example:

```
size_t boolsize = 10 * sizeof(bool);

struct example *ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr + boolsize);
```

This way you call malloc only once and memory is layed out contiguously

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the size of the array in advance you can simply make it a pointer and allocate it later.

```
typedef struct example {
    bool* arr;  // <-- Pointer
    int size;   // <-- Size of the array
} example_t;
```

Creating a new array follows the same steps.

```
example_t* newExample(int size) {
    int i;
    example_t* example = malloc(sizeof(example_t));
    example->arr = malloc(sizeof(bool) * size);
    example->size = size;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
      example->arr[i] = false;
    return example;
}
```

**Don't forget to free the memory of the `bool arr` and the `struct` itself after use!**

Answer (score 1):

The last member of a struct is allowed to be an array of unspecified size, known as "flexible array member", so your declaration is correct.* It's your responsibility to calculate the correct size for malloc, so in your case, do:

```
example_t* example = malloc(sizeof(example_t) + SIZE * sizeof(bool));
```

If you want it initialized to `0` (`false` in a typical bool type), either use `calloc`:

```
example_t* example = calloc(1, sizeof(example_t) + SIZE * sizeof(bool));
```

Or initialize after malloc using `memset`:

```
memset(example, 0, sizeof(example_t) + SIZE * sizeof(bool));
```

*) as long as there are other members in your struct preceeding the array. Otherwise the struct would be useless and you could just allocate the plain array:

```
bool *example = malloc(SIZE * sizeof(bool));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do these stuff:

Structure definition:

```
typedef struct example {
    bool *arr; 
} example_t;
```

Creation:

```
example_t *newExample(int SIZE){
    example_t *example = malloc(sizeof(example_t));
    example->arr = malloc(SIZE*sizeof(bool)) // allocate space for arr
    for(int i = 0;i < SIZE;i++)
        example->arr[i] = false; // initialize all of arr elements to false
    return example;
}
```

Optionally, you can also keep a variable in the struct to store the size of `arr` array (alongside the `*arr`), so that you can use that later when accessing the `arr` array.

You will have to manually use [`free()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/) when the usage of the structure `example` is finished.